# Which commit introduced a file?

Tags: git

I want to find out which commit introduced a file.  I'm currently doing:

```
git log --reverse --pretty="%h" <filename> | head -n 1
```

but I realize that this is very expensive.  Is there a way to do it faster (using cheaper plubming commands)?  Perhaps by bisecting history?

Comment: I doubt it. Git history is kept as a linked list, so you can only track the path from a commit back to the beginning. In order to bisect the history, you will need to first track the history one commit at a time, and you already have O(n) right there. The best you can hope for is to look at the tree of each commit while traversing, and terminate early before reaching the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you don't need `git log`, but just `git rev-list`:

```
git rev-list HEAD -- <filename> | tail -n 1
```

or

```
git rev-list --reverse HEAD -- <filename> | head -n 1
```

Basically the same command as `git log`, but it only returns
the SHA-1 of the commits, so the overhead of formatting the log message
is lost. Whether that overhead is significant compared to walking the
history is another question.

It's possible to use `git rev-list --bisect` to implement your own
binary search, but the repeated calls to `git rev-list` necessary almost
certainly will be slower than just piping a single call to either `head` or `tail`.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
git log --oneline <filename> | tail -1
```

Comment: First, `--oneline` is just shorthand for `--pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit`: it doesn't escape the pretty processing in any way, and hence isn't faster.  Second, commit limiting using `-<n>` is arguably better than spawning another command-line utility (`tail -1` in this case) and piping to it.

Comment: Yes, but this solution actually works. That must count for something? :) Ah I see you edited the tail command into your question. Glad to have helped!

Comment: Oops, sorry: edited question to use `head -n 1`, since `-1` gets applied before `--reverse`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a rough idea of when you added the file, you can try

```
git log --reverse --until 2012-06-01 -n 1 -- <filename>
```

if you are fairly sure that the file wasn't introduced after 2012-06-01. The combination of `--reverse` and `-n 1` show only the first commit earlier than the given date. If you don't get any results, your estimate is too early, and you need to try a later date.

Given the way `git` stores history (using a directed acyclic graph), I don't think `git log` is doing significantly more work than you would need to do by stringing together lower-level plumbing commands.

Comment: Hm, date-based commit limiting to speed things up.  However, as you might have guessed, I'm executing this from within a script.  Does that mean that I have to store my guesses corresponding to each file for my script?  What are your thoughts on programatically bisecting history?

Comment: Ugly. I think any attempt, since multiple calls to git would be needed, would be slower than your original idea. See my other answer for simply replacing `git log` with `git rev-list`.

Answer (score 0):

Use diff-filter=A

```
git log --reverse --format=%H --name-status --diff-filter=A -- file1 file2 | grep ^A | cut -f2
```

For any number of files, you'll get the required ordering in one traversal.